# How to edit crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I new to programming. With limited knowledge I have done small application. But I want to use Crystal reports to view the reports. Can anyone help me to understand how to edit crystal reports, coz I need to change the view of the report. When trying to open in Visual studio installed with crystal reports , it is showing all 00's and FF's.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

use version 2012 for visual studio.
the patch for crystal report for visual studio is not out yet

here's the link [Visual studio 2013 & crystal report](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3482977)